# Why continuation when no records match criteria?

Tags: azure-table-storage

Is it reasonable to assume that the presence of continuation partionkey and rowkey indicate that more records are available and the absence of continuation indicate there are no more records?

The reason I'm asking is because the following query returns no records at all (due to the filter criteria) but continuation is still returned. I'm confused, how am I supposed to know whether there are more records or not when querying table storage?

```
var query = (from s in myStorageServiceContext.CreateQuery<Customer>("Customers")
             where false
             select s).Take(1000) as DataServiceQuery<Customer>;

var response = (QueryOperationResponse)query.Execute();

string nextRowKey = null;
string nextPartitionKey = null;
response.Headers.TryGetValue("x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey", out nextPartitionKey);
response.Headers.TryGetValue("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey", out nextRowKey);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPartitionKey)) throw new Exception("NextPartitionKey is not null");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRowKey)) throw new Exception("NextRowKey is not null");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the absence of continuation indicates that there are no more records.

Continuation token returns in the following cases:

1. If the number of entities to be returned exceeds 1,000.
2. if the server timeout interval is exceeded
3. if the query crosses the partition boundary

for more information please see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

KK